# Timing how long a function takes

Tags: ios, objective-c

*I've seen Q/A here about timing function duration in other languages but didn't find anything in Objective-C. If there is one, post the link and I will delete this question*

I want to measure the time it takes for some functions to run. I've cobbled together the bits of code below but I wonder if there is a more compact or portable way to do this.

```
 CFTimeInterval startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

 // do some work

 CFTimeInterval difference = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime;

 printf("elapsed:  %f\n", difference)
```

Comment: No,This is the best way using CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(); its Absolute time is measured in seconds relative to the absolute reference date of Jan 1 2001 00:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to precisely time very short timespans there are two additional timing facilities with very low overhead that come to my mind:

- [`mach_absolute_time`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html) with nanosecond resolution
- [`__builtin_readcyclecounter`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-functions): a clang builtin function to read a low-latency, high-accuracy clock.

Answer (score 3):

No,This is the best way using CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(); 
its Absolute time is measured in seconds relative to the absolute reference date of Jan 1 2001 00:00:00 GMT